# When does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ imply $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis

This is just a general question. I know the opposite statement is always true. I'm just asking when the converse holds. I know that the converse is not true in some cases, such as for harmonic series. What additional restrictions are needed to make this statement true?

Comment: Are you aware of the convergence tests?

Comment: When $a_n$ heads to $0$ quickly enough. There are various "tests" that quantify how "quick" is "quick enough".

Comment: @AaronMaroja yes. But I would like to impose some restrictions on $a_n$ if possible so that I know the series converges without using the convergence test.

Comment: I had misread the title. Once I realized, I deleted the useless answer I had added.

Comment: @DavidMitra Could you point me to those tests? I have never heard of those before. Thank you.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests).

Comment: @user90593 Never heard? You just said you knew...

Comment: @AaronMaroja I know the convergence tests. I don't know the tests to quantify how "quickly" is quick is enough for $a_n$ to approach $0$ so that the series converges. These are two different things.

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Would you please show an example?

Comment: @AaronMaroja specifically could you show how to quantify that "quickliness" to ensure converge of $\sum a_n$?

Comment: D'Alembert and Cauchy Tests will give you what you want, for example.

Comment: For instance $|a_n|$ might decay faster than the terms of convergent Geometric Series. This is what the Ratio and Root tests are based on.

Comment: @DavidMitra I removed my post, it was wrong (as you pointed out), thanks.

Comment: well you could go in an ultrametric space ...

Answer (score 2):

There is the alternating series test.
Let $a_n>0$ and $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ for all $n$. Now, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^na_n$ converges.

Comment: This is the same as my answer, written differently.

Comment: Yes. It hadn't been posted when I started my answer. :)

Comment: Although,  I believe the absolute value of the terms need to be strictly decreasing, at least for large enough $n$.

Comment: No, the monotinicity need not be strict.

Comment: @David Mitra Ah yes. Quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any natural criterion where
$$ x_n\to 0 \land \text{such-and-such} \implies \sum_n x_n \text{ converges}$$
except where "such-and-such" *alone* implies that the series converges.

(Of course one could have *unnatural* examples, e.g. let "such-and-such" be "either $x_n\to 42$ or $\sum_n x_n$ converges" -- but that is even less enlightening.)

Comment: Arguably Tim's answer is a counterexample to this claim.